# Laravel once defind yield content

Tags: php, laravel, view, laravel-4, frameworks

I a'm trying to yield my content from controllers. But I don't want to define again and again that I want to yield the 'Content' section

How can I archive this, so I don't need to place

```
@section('body')
<h1>Content</h1>
<p>More content</p>
@stop
```

again is every view

For example, ASP.NET MVC with RenderBody()

Comment: Where have you used `yield` in your `view` ? Where is your controller code ? Are you using `Blade template` which `extends` a master layout ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Blade` templating engin, create a master `layout` in your `app/views/layouts' folder something like this template:

```
<!-- master.blade.php -->
<html>

    <head></head>

    <body>
         <div class="container">
             @yield('content')
         </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Then in your every child view, just extend the master `view`, for example:

```
<!-- home.blade.php -->
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('body')
    <h1>Content</h1>
    <p>More content</p>
@stop
```

So, whenever you'll use something like this:

```
return View::make('home');
```

Your child view will extend the master view and content will be yielded inside the `div.container`.

Comment: The problem is that I don't want to use 'section' for every view again. I want to set de section for once en never repeat it for the child-views